# Find the only button that is enabled on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have numerous buttons on one page, on click this will set them to disabled with the following:

```
$( this ).prop('disabled', true);
```

I have a counter that does a simple count so that I know when one button is left unclicked. What I then need to do is grab the text from that button that is left. It could be any one of the buttons from 1-7, so in theory I want to grab the first button that is enabled.

I tried the following, however I'm pretty sure it will just grab the first button, and doesn't really care about the property state:

```
alert($('button:first').prop('enabled',true).text());
```

What is the correct way to grab the first enabled button on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `$('button:first').prop('enabled',true).text()` you *directly enable* the first button (by setting its `enabled` attribute to `true`) and then get its text, while you want to find the first enabled one.

I'd suggest using selectors, just like you did to access the first button:

```
$('button:enabled:first').text()
```